# How PIN (Positive Intrinsic Negative) junctions work?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Studying the operation of the photodetectors I came across the PIN (Positive  Intrinsic Negative) junctions. Honestly, I have not found very clear material on the Internet.

Exactly how do these PIN (Positive  Intrinsic Negative) junctions work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that an "intrinsic" layer of semiconductor, neither P nor N, will contain no free charge carriers in equilibrium. Photoelectric detection works best in depleted material with no free charge carriers around. If there are free charge carriers, they interfere with the collection of the photoelectric charge.

In reality, it is generally impossible to make perfectly intrinsic material, so a PIN diode is merely a diode with a very lightly doped layer between cathode and anode. It may still require a substantial bias to deplete that layer. For example, the [Hamamatsu S2744](https://www.hamamatsu.com/content/dam/hamamatsu-photonics/sites/documents/99_SALES_LIBRARY/ssd/s2744-08_etc_kpin1049e.pdf) is intended for operation with 70V of bias.

Comment: and I believe the main reason this is used is that it gives a bigger volume for light collection, right?

Comment: @user253751 That's one reason, especially important for silicon photoelectric infrared and x-ray detectors. Another is that it reduces the detector capacitance, which reduces the effect of amplifier voltage noise on sensitivity. For charged particle detection you collect more charge from each particle because the tracks are longer. For rectifier diodes it increases the breakdown voltage.